# Segmentation fault when accessing array via pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, operator-precedence

I have a global array declared as

```
int Team1[12][8];
```

When I call the function

```
int readLineupB(int teamNr){

      int (*teamToRead)[12][8];
      teamToRead = &Team1;

      for (int currentPlayersNumber = 1; currentPlayersNumber<11; currentPlayersNumber++) {
        for (int otherNumber = 1; otherNumber<7; otherNumber++) {
            *teamToRead[currentPlayersNumber][otherNumber] = 20;
        }
    } 
    return 1;
}
```

it fills the array until position [10],[3], then seemingly for [10],[4] I get a segmentation fault, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: how about `(*teamToRead)[currentPlayersNumber][otherNumber] = 20;`?

Comment: C arrays start indexing with `0` and goes upto `N-1`...

Comment: @M.M deleted :D too little sleep / coffee.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh, the parentheses solve it! About the array's start at 0 I know, I just had reduced the "width" of assigments to exclude an error at the edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Check the data types.**

`teamToRead` is a pointer to `int [12][8]` array.

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the subscript operator binds higher that the dereference.

So, in case of

```
  *teamToRead[currentPlayersNumber][otherNumber] = 20;
```

you're trying to say something like

```
  *(* ( teamToRead + currentPlayersNumber ) ) [otherNumber] = 20;
```

where, the pointer arithmetic becomes illegal as they honor the pointer type and thereby ventures out of bounds.

To solve that, you need to enforce the precedence of the dereference by explicit parentheses, like

```
 (*teamToRead)[currentPlayersNumber][otherNumber] = 20;
```

Comment: I would not have expected this precedence, which of course explains the error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to forgo the pointer to 2-dimensional array, and just use pointer to (first of array of) one-dimensional array:

```
int Team1[12][8];

int readLineupB(int teamNr){
    // declare teamToRead as a pointer to array of 8 ints
    int (*teamToRead)[8];

    // Team1 is of type int x[12][8] that readily decays 
    // to int (*x)[8]
    teamToRead = Team1;

    for (int currentPlayersNumber = 1; currentPlayersNumber<11; currentPlayersNumber++) {
        for (int otherNumber = 1; otherNumber<7; otherNumber++) {
            // no dereference here.
            teamToRead[currentPlayersNumber][otherNumber] = 20;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution requires less writing, thanks. However, I prefer Sourav's, because it seems easier to understand for me. One sees immediately that the variable is a pointer to a two-dimensional array.